# Select Specific value from a table

Tags: sql, oracle

```
ID  FName   Lname   Status  Major Code  GPA Admitted Date
101 Tom     Smith   Freshman    103     3.51    3-May-2015
```

I have a table with these columns, I need to "list the sophomores who were admitted before 2015" Now I've got the admitted before 2015 part down, but I am struggling with selecting only sophomores throughout this large table.

I'm thinking I'll need to use DISTINCT or WHERE IN but I'm not sure how to select sophomore as the table doesn't recognize that

SELECT status, fname, lname, gpa, admitteddate
FROM mytablename
WHERE status = 'JUNIOR' AND
TO_CHAR(admitteddate, 'YYYY') <=2014;

This is the correct query, thank you!

Comment: What values do you have in `Status` column?

Comment: Status column just has the grades, so there is freshman, soph, junior and senior. I can't select specific rows as there are too many for that.

Comment: @Jon please post what you tried so far.

Comment: @1010 I posted below under the answer what I have so far.

Comment: SELECT status, fname, lname, gpa, admitteddate  

   FROM mytable  


    WHERE status = 'sophomore'  


    TO_CHAR(admitteddate, 'YYYY') < 2015;  


I get a sql command not properly ended error

Comment: Please add all extra information to your question, you can edit it. If your query produces an error include the message you get.

Comment: @1010 I am not sure what you mean all extra information. I added the query and error in the main post

Answer (score 1):

I assume the `Status` column is the one with the key information. If you have rows with `Sophomore` in this column, it is as simple as adding `Status = 'Sophomore'` to the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: SELECT status, fname, lname, gpa, admitteddate

   FROM mytable

    WHERE status = 'sophomore'

    TO_CHAR(adimitteddate, 'YYYY') < 2015; 

I get a sql command not properly ended error